# What causes bosses to appear in Loop Hero?

Tags: loop-hero

Bosses seem to appear somewhat randomly, not after a certain amount of loops. Is it random, or is there something (number of kills, number of buildings etc.) that causes bosses to appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you place tiles in the world, there is a bar that fills up slowly from left to right, below the day's progress bar.  When this bar is completely filled, the boss for that act will appear.  You can use this to time your boss interactions if you're not ready on a certain loop.

Placing any tile into the world directly adds a small amount to this bar

[image: bossbar]

Comment: What causes the bar to fill up?

Comment: @fredley Every time you place a new tile the bar fills a little more

Comment: Additionally, using an Oblivion card to remove a tile reduces the world completion bar by an equivalent amount (though if it was already full, this will not ‘unsummon’ the boss).

Comment: With regard to Oblivion, I don't know if it's a bug but it seems to add to the boss bar before removing anything, so if you have just one tile's worth remaining before the boss is summoned Oblivion seems to summon it.